# MVC 5 - Localize Unique Validations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

So I'm trying out FluentValidation to validate my models in a MVC 5 project.

Everything is going fine but I came across an Issue I don't know how to fix.

I have everything localized to english and portuguese. And if I try to register a user that already exists this creates a message like:

```
Name 'example@mail.com' is already taken
Email 'example@mail.com' is already taken
```

I'm using the authentication system that came with the new MVC 5 project because this is only a prototype test project.

I've created this method to use in the validator:

```
public bool UniqueNameEmail(RegisterViewModel model, string nameemail)
{
    ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var dbModel = _db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == nameemail.ToLower())
                               .SingleOrDefault();
    if (dbModel == null) return true;

    return dbModel.Email == model.Email;
}
```

If your wondering why I used name and email it is because the name is always equal to the email registered.
Then I use it like this:

```
RuleFor(registerViewModel => registerViewModel.Email).Must(UniqueNameEmail).WithLocalizedMessage(() => Resource.Unique_Field)
```

But the Entity validations override the one that come from the validator.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can someone help?

Comment: @Damir Arh Do you know what is going on?

Comment: I have the same issue. I moved all literals to a resource file and translated them. Only the 'Name ... is already taken' message I can't translate. Did you ever solved this?

Comment: @PaulMeems Sadly no. I had to abandon FluentValidation. Never touched it again